# Using TorrentFlux's Download Action Programmatically

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

**Summary** : I'm coding a script which automatically download **.torrent** file from isohunt.com and then download that torrent to **DOWNLOADS** folder. But i can't download contents of torrent.

I have a torrent file (**file.torrent**) . I can use TorrentFlux's WebApp interface and download torrent file. But i want to start download programmatically.

I found TorrentFLux WebApp using dispatcher.php file like this to start downloading :

```
dispatcher.php?action=start&transfer=_file.torrent
```

I'm trying request this file with cUrl, but it's not working.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/torrentflux/html/dispatcher.php?action=start&transfer=file.torrent");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_close();
```

Note : I'm asking here because Torrentflux official forum has database error.

Comment: Try `$result = curl_exec($ch); var_dump($result);` and see if it is returning any errors.  Do you need to be logged in to use TorrentFlux web app?

Comment: result of `var_dump($result);` : `string(0) ""`

Comment: check that your curl code can download files from other sites, then check your filename to see if it needs to be url-encoded. then check torrentflux to see if the torrentflux is actually responding to urls